# How does PublishProcessor.offer() knows that downstream hasn't consumed previous emit?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I use PublishProcessor.offer() to emit from the upstream. I read(*) that it may return false if a subscriber is not ready to receive next event, because PublishProcessor doesn't coordinate backpressure. I would like to know how it works. **How does PublishProcessor know that subscribers are not ready?**

I read that upstream may know about the potential of downstream to process emissions through reactive pull:

```
someObservable.subscribe(new Subscriber<t>() {
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
      request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
      // gracefully handle sequence-complete
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
      // gracefully handle error
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(t n) {
      // do something with the emitted item "n"
      // request another item:
      request(1);
    }
});
```

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure

But my subscription looks like that:

```
publishProcessor.subscribe(new Consumer<T>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(T t) throws Exception {
                    // do IO
                }
            }, Log::submitCrash);
```

Does it internally call request(1); after accept() is finished, or it doesn't perform reactive pull? I tried to read the code and it doesn't seems so. This Consumer is passed to LambdaSubscriber. And LambdaSubscriber.onNext() doesn't invoke request(n).

the javadoc of this subscribe method:

```
 public final Disposable subscribe(Consumer<? super T> onNext, Consumer<? super Throwable> onError)
```

says: The operator consumes the source {@code Publisher} in an unbounded manner (i.e., no
 backpressure is applied to it).

So it says nothing about reactive pull. Does consuming source in unbounded manner means that unbounded backpressure buffer is applied to this subscription or no backpressure buffer at all?

Is there an other mechanism for PublishProcessor to know if it's subscribers are finished with consumption of emitted values?

(*)

> PublishProcessor is a Flowable as well as a FlowableProcessor,
>   however, it does not coordinate backpressure between different
>   subscribers and between an upstream source and a subscriber. If an
>   upstream item is received via onNext(Object), if a subscriber is not
>   ready to receive an item, that subscriber is terminated via a
>   MissingBackpressureException. To avoid this case, use offer(Object)
>   and retry sometime later if it returned false.

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/processors/PublishProcessor.html

Answer (score 1):

Each `Subscriber` receives a special `Subscription` that tracks the `request` amount the consumer has issued and [decrements](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/3.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/processors/PublishProcessor.java#L359-L360) this amount if the `PublishProcessor` could call `onNext` on the `Subscriber`.

The consumer is considered not-ready if this tracked amount [is zero](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/3.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/processors/PublishProcessor.java#L400) and checked [inside `offer`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/3.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/processors/PublishProcessor.java#L294).

If you consume the `PublishProcessor` synchronously and issue `request` from within `onNext`, the tracked amount will be always greater than zero thus `offer` can go through.

However, if you consume asynchronousy, for example, by applying `observeOn`, there is now a bounded buffer between the processor and your consumer that could fill up and the tracked request amount could end up as zero, preventing `offer` to signal more.

Unbounded consumption means that the consumer issues `request(Long.MAX_VALUE)`, which is interpreted as the consumer is ready to receive any number of items. `PublishProcessor` itself would [do this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/3.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/rxjava3/processors/PublishProcessor.java#L234-L235) in case you subscribed it to another `Publisher`.

In general, unbounded doesn't imply unlimited buffering because the particular consumer may throw away, batch, sample or process items synchronously on the caller thread of `onNext` thus no overflow would happen.